# Visual Studio 2015 Apache Cordova Project Files not included to project and hidden

Tags: apache, visual-studio, file, cordova

I updated to VS Community Edition Update 3 and now my cordova project files not included to project and hidden.

[image]

i removed and reinstalled "tools for apache cordova update 10".
i uninstalled VS Community and reinstalled again.

But not resolved problem. what is the problem?

[ActivityLog.xml](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Byo9c7j0vM5xYlpUSVg2ZVBXaHc)

Comment: It looks like you had a package load failure. Can you open %APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ActivityLog.xml and post the contents online so I can have a look?

Comment: i update my question with activitylog.xml file.

Comment: Thanks @Cem. The log indicates that your MEF cache is corrupt. Can you try deleting %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache, restarting Visual Studio and try again?

Comment: not resolved. my project files still hidden. i'm including to project manually. but this time that is not debugging and return error. thanks.

Comment: any solution do you have?

Answer (score -1):

We had the same issue and in our case it was something to do with `typescript`. So what we installed the `typescript` for vs 2015. You can download `typescript` for VS 2015 from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593). Try and let me know. Good luck

Comment: i uninsalled old version typescript tools. i downloaded your suggested download and installed. but not resolved. thank you.

Comment: This is working for me.So Why downvote ?? wtf? people are trying to help you. just give them a thumbs up. noob.

Comment: my problem is not interested with this answer.